# How to retrieve an integer part of a URL?

Tags: php

I would like to retrieve part of a url like the last part that will always be an integer. But I don't know how to do it as the last part will change e.g `file/Post.php?id=1` and then it could also be `file/Post.php?id=26569413146456`

How can I do this?

Comment: why can't you use $_GET['id]??

Comment: Is the URL the referrer to the current page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it from request, use;

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

If you want to get it from string, use;

```
$temp = explode("id=", $your_url);
$id = $temp[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The $_REQUEST variable contains both GET and POST arguments.

```
$_REQUEST['id']
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

If you will only use http get to fetch the page $_GET['id'] may be used instead but REQUEST contains arguments for GET POST and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is the one that requested the current page, you can simply use

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Otherwise, for some arbitrary string that you know to contain a URL, you can use `parse_url` to grab the query string from the URL and `parse_str` to break down the query components:

```
$id = "";
$query_string = parse_url($url_string, PHP_URL_QUERY);

if ($query_string) {
   parse_str($query_string, $query);

   if (isset($query['id'])) {
      $id = $query['id'];
   }
}
```